# UIImageView in full screen mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

**My Goal:**

I have a UIImageView which displays a single image to the user. The view is in a UIView. When the user taps on the image I would like it to go into a full screen mode. Much like the current Facebook and eBay iOS apps do on iPhone.

Once in this mode, the user can zoom on the image and when done - swipe up / down on the image and it then goes back to the last view.

**Problem**

I am not entirely sure how this is done. On the apps mentioned, there is a new bar that appears at the bottom of the screen - the bar allows the user to do other actions. This, along with the swipe gesture makes me believe this full screen mode is actually presented with a new view controller. Also I noticed that as you scroll up or down on the eBay iOS app, the background starts to change to a clear colour where you see the view it was presented from. I did not know this was possible with a UIViewController when dismissing it? 
I just am not too sure how it is done.

I tried setting my UIImageView to full screen - but it misses everything else as described above.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would present a new view controller in front of the first one with the image full screen and, optionally, other controls.
I think the effect of seeing the presenting view controller behind is obtained taking a snapshot of it and setting it as the background of the presented view controller (with the method drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates: or other if < iOS7, see [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1817/_index.html)).

Comment: I had no idea about the snapshot feature. That's pretty awesome! I tested out the idea in eBay's iOS app and it looks exactly like that as the  background image it shows is showing old data. It seems that's how they do it.